# How to increase creation speed on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I try to load vertex on AgensGraph.

But, upload speed is too slow.

```
agens=# \timing on
Timing is on.
agens=# create (:v1{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
Time: 23.285 ms
```

How can I increase creation speed on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid lost data, DBMS must sync to disk before commit.

It takes much time to commit.

You does not mind it.

Option "synchronous_commit" helps you.

```
agens=# set synchronous_commit to off;
SET
Time: 0.205 ms
agens=# create (:v1{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
Time: 0.360 ms
agens=# set synchronous_commit to on;
SET
Time: 0.234 ms
agens=# create (:v1{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
Time: 33.787 ms
```